# Taint a node in kubernetes live cluster

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

How can I achieve the same command with a YAML file such that I can do a `kubectl apply -f`? The command below works and it taints but I can't figure out how to use it via a manifest file.

```
$ kubectl taint nodes \
          172.4.5.2-3a1d4eeb \
          kops.k8s.io/instancegroup=loadbalancer \
          NoSchedule
```

Comment: I was not able to write my whole question due to some syntx errors: so real question is how can i achieve the same command above with a yaml file such that i can do "kubectl apply -f taint-lbNode.yaml"

The command i posted works and it taints but i could not figure out how to put it in yaml format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `-o yaml` option and save the resulting YAML file and make sure to remove the status and some extra stuff, this will apply the taint , but provide you the yaml that you can later use to do `kubectl apply -f` , and save it to version control ( even if you create the resource from command line and later get the yaml and apply it , it will not re-create the resource , so it is perfectly fine )

**Note:** Most of the commands support `--dry-run` , that will just generate the yaml and not create the resource , but in this case , I could not make it work with `--dry-run` , may be this command does not support that flag.

```
C02W84XMHTD5:~ iahmad$ kubectl taint node minikube dedicated=foo:PreferNoSchedule -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
  annotations:
    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: "0"
    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: "true"
  creationTimestamp: 2018-10-16T21:44:03Z
  labels:
    beta.kubernetes.io/arch: amd64
    beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
    kubernetes.io/hostname: minikube
    node-role.kubernetes.io/master: ""
  name: minikube
  resourceVersion: "291136"
  selfLink: /api/v1/nodes/minikube
  uid: 99a1a304-d18c-11e8-9334-f2cf3c1f0864
spec:
  externalID: minikube
  taints:
  - effect: PreferNoSchedule
    key: dedicated
    value: foo
```

then use the yaml with kubectl apply:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Node
metadata:
  name: minikube
spec:
  taints:
  - effect: PreferNoSchedule
    key: dedicated
    value: foo
```

Comment: Well, technically the first invocation already does the taint. So while you're right in suggesting to use `-o yaml` to generate the YAML you should also append `--dry-run` so that you only get the resulting YAML but the command itself is not executed. Please update your answer.

Comment: i tried dry run was not working with this command , unknown flag: --dry-run

Comment: @MichaelHausenblas the falg was not working with that command , though it is working with run command kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --dry-run -o yaml

Comment: okay, am gonna run now: but one more clarification: do i need to apply the entire yaml or just the taint part? coz my -o yaml is huge.

Comment: @FnameLname -o yaml is just for infomration , you just need to take out the relevant part

Comment: ok got it. so i have 3 nodes and 3 Masters: now, can i apply this to the instance group so its applied to all the nodes? such that i don't have to lookup node name and do it dynamically which makes automation easier? my master and proxy node are running in two different IGs

Comment: I am trying to accomplish this via helm chart for automation:.any hint how can I apply to the particular node all the time I run helm install?
the node name keeps on changing as its part of cluster. But can I use some label on the node that stays as is and when I do helm install, it does apply to the node that matches the label?

Comment: basically, how do i use helm to apply this change only to the node i need?

Comment: @AhmFM you cant use helm for this purpose

Comment: i see.. i will try to file an enhancement request for this.

Answer (score 0):

I have two nodes in my cluster, please look at labels

```
kubectl get nodes --show-labels
NAME          STATUS   ROLES   AGE    VERSION   LABELS
172.16.2.53   Ready    node    7d4h   v1.19.7   type=primary
172.16.2.89   Ready    node    33m    v1.19.7   type=secondary
```

Lets say I want to taint node name with "172.16.2.89"

```
kubectl taint node 172.16.2.89  type=secondary:NoSchedule 
node/172.16.2.89 tainted
```

Example -

```
kubectl taint node <node-name>  <label-key>=<value>:NoSchedule
```

I have two nodes in my cluster, please look at labels

> NoExecute means the pod will be evicted from the node.

> NoSchedule means the scheduler will not place the pod onto the node